# If statement skipping || if first condition is false

Tags: java

I have a search function that checks if the searchKey matches an Objects Attribute. Instead of going through all attributes it stops if the first check is false. Heres the code

```
else if (address.getLastName() != null ? address.getLastName().toLowerCase().contains(searchKey) : false
                    || address.getFirstName() != null ? address.getFirstName().toLowerCase().contains(searchKey) : false
                    || address.getTitle() != null ? address.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(searchKey) : false
                    || address.getStreet() != null ? address.getStreet().toLowerCase().contains(searchKey) : false
                    || Integer.toString(address.getPlz()).equals(searchKey)) {
                outputList.add(address);
```

So if the lastname is smith and the firstname is sam, and the searchKey is sam, it will stop after finding that Lastname!= sam.

Test that fails:

```
 @Test
    public void searchFirstNameTest() {
        Address address1 = new Address();
        address.setFirstName("sam");
        address.setLastName("smith");
        address1.setFirstName("bob");
        input.add(address);
        input.add(address1);

        List<Address> result = testee.searchAddress("sam", input);

        assertEquals(1, result.size());
        assertEquals("sam", result.get(0).getFirstName());
    }
```

where am i going wrong?

Comment: Can you replicate this behavior in a minimal but complete example to demonstrate?  If your claim is that the `||` operator in Java is broken then it seems *far* more likely that your test has a mistake in it instead.

Comment: Using a ternary operator inside an if condition check seems like a horrible idea and the result is as unreadable as expected.

Comment: Pro tips : don't make such complicated conditions, it's hard to read and hard to debug. Use intermediate boolean (such as `boolean isLastNameOK = address.getLastName() != null ? address.getLastName().toLowerCase().contains(searchKey) : false;`) and then use your boolean in your condition.It will be more readable, and to debug you just have to "display" or watch in debugger the value of your boolean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution may be, that you need to put your statements in brackets.

```
else if ((address.getLastName() != null ? address.getLastName().toLowerCase().contains(searchKey) : false)
                    || (address.getFirstName() != null ? address.getFirstName().toLowerCase().contains(searchKey) : false)
                    || (address.getTitle() != null ? address.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(searchKey) : false)
                    || (address.getStreet() != null ? address.getStreet().toLowerCase().contains(searchKey) : false)
                    || Integer.toString(address.getPlz()).equals(searchKey)) {
                outputList.add(address);
```

Otherwise the statements are not executed in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

> where am i going wrong?

You think that `A ? B : C || D ? E : F` means `(A ? B : C) || (D ? E : F)`, however [operator precedence](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/) dictates that it actually means:

```java
A ? B : ( (C || D) ? E : F )
```

The expression should be:

```java
else if ((address.getLastName() != null ? address.getLastName().toLowerCase().contains(searchKey) : false)
        || (address.getFirstName() != null ? address.getFirstName().toLowerCase().contains(searchKey) : false)
        || (address.getTitle() != null ? address.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(searchKey) : false)
        || (address.getStreet() != null ? address.getStreet().toLowerCase().contains(searchKey) : false)
        || Integer.toString(address.getPlz()).equals(searchKey)) {
    outputList.add(address);
```

Although it is better written without using ternary conditional operator:

```java
else if ((address.getLastName() != null && address.getLastName().toLowerCase().contains(searchKey))
        || (address.getFirstName() != null && address.getFirstName().toLowerCase().contains(searchKey))
        || (address.getTitle() != null && address.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(searchKey))
        || (address.getStreet() != null && address.getStreet().toLowerCase().contains(searchKey))
        || Integer.toString(address.getPlz()).equals(searchKey)) {
    outputList.add(address);
```

Which *can* be written without the extra parentheses, **but you shouldn't**:

```java
else if (address.getLastName() != null && address.getLastName().toLowerCase().contains(searchKey)
        || address.getFirstName() != null && address.getFirstName().toLowerCase().contains(searchKey)
        || address.getTitle() != null && address.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(searchKey)
        || address.getStreet() != null && address.getStreet().toLowerCase().contains(searchKey)
        || Integer.toString(address.getPlz()).equals(searchKey)) {
    outputList.add(address);
```

Always use explicit parentheses when mixing `&&`, `||`, and `?:` operators.

Answer (score -1):

`||` is lazy. If the left side is false we know that the result will be false, and the right side is not evaluated.

I suggest you rewrite your logic to be simpler with returns instead.

Comment: "|| is lazy. If the left side is false we know that the result will be false" <- No, that would be for &&. with the or its the other way around: If one part is proven true everything else is true. `false || true` evaluates to `true` after all

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Well, that just demonstrates that the code in the question is hard to read.